# How do I translate hard coded words in twig file

Tags: 8, theming, i18n-l10n

Is there a way to translate hard coded words in twig when selecting a language from the language dropdown? I have used the `|t` `({{ myword|t }})` function but it doesn't seem to be work when selecting another language.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: eh? yeah, that's what the whole localization set of modules is for. go to modules section and in the localization enable translations and then you will have translation UI available.

Comment: Could you please explain more. I didn’t get what you said

Comment: thanks @IvanJaros. It worked. There is a module named interface translations. It should be enabled. Then the translations can be updated in .PO files

Answer (score 2):

`{{ myword }}` is a variable, not a string. You need to use `{{ 'myword'|t }}` (with quotes)

Comment: Still no luck :( It doesn’t get translated. It still shows the english word when on translations

Comment: Make sure you have: Cleared cache, then loaded page in the default language, once you have done this, you can go to the Trans UI and add a translation for 'myword'.  You may need to clear cache as well before it will show up on the new lang node.

Comment: @iambatman What is the status 'myword' show up in the list of strings for that language?